# Can `dired-do-compress` unzip to a different directory by default?

Tags: dired, compression

If I try to unzip a file, it will put the unzipped file in the same directory as the zip file. Is there any way to make it uncompress to a particular directory all the time?

Answer (score 1):

No. But if you want to move it to a different directory, just use `R` after you `dired-do-compress`. This works whether you are (un)zipping one file or a thousand files (the marked files in the dir). Both `Z` and `R` act on the marked files, or the file of the cursor if none are marked.

If you don't want to use `Z` (`dired-do-compress`) and then `R` (`dired-do-rename`), then just define a command that first does `dired-do-compress` and then does `dired-do-rename`.

But both of those commands, and their underlying functions, prompt you for the target directory name. To hard-code that target you would need to fiddle a bit with the underlying code. (Not really worth it, IMO.)

You can also put the target directory name in a register (or the secondary selection), so you can insert it with a keystroke. And you can also use `M-p` to retrieve from previous use as an input.